# ASP.NET MVC - change button name in the same view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I change button name in a same view, my view is "**_CreateOrUpdate**", I want to call Save Action my button name change is Save and else when I call Update Action my button change Update.

```
<div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save"><i class="icon-save"></i>Save</button>
```

Comment: how you are deciding that which action will be hit by your view???

Comment: I suggest that separate create and update actions in two views.

Comment: use `ViewBag.SubmitText = "Save"` or `ViewBag.SubmitText = "Update"` and set in the actions that will return `_CreateOrUpdate`, `<button value="@ViewBag.SubmitText">.. @ViewBag.SubmitText</button>`

Comment: In your button use something like `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="@ViewBag.CreateOrUpdate">` and in the controller ActionResult method that returns the View you set that variable to `Save` or `Update` accordingly: `ViewBag.CreateOrUpdate = "Save"` or `ViewBag.CreateOrUpdate = "Update"`

Comment: thanks all I have resolved my problem :)

@UğurAldanmaz you are so funny :) sorry for my English

Comment: Nope bro. You are so funny too. Happy day and happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a property in the model for the button text.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{                   
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save"><i class="icon-save"></i>@Model.ButtonName</button>
}
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nMIjws)

Answer (score 1):

this is solution for my answer.

```
    @if (ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action") == "Create")
      {
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save"><i class="icon-save"></i> Save</button>
      }
      else
      {
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Edit"><i class="icon-save"></i> Save changes</button>
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple *JS* function for this which will change button value. When the page is *ready*:

```
var button = document.getElementById("saveButton");
button.value = [Basically anything you want to pass from controller];
```

Another option is to use *razor* and `ViewBag` to pass something from controller. This is easier if you want just to pass *Save*/*Update* from controller:

```
ViewBag.CreateUpdate = "Save";
```

and in the view:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-save"></i>@ViewBag.CreateUpdate</button>
```